# C#: String as parameter to event?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, event-handling

I have a GUI-thread for my form and another thread that computes things.

The form has a richtTextBox. I want the worker-thread to pass strings to the form, so that every string is displayed in the textbox.

Everytime a new string is generated in the worker thread I call an event, and this should now display the string.
But I don't know how to pass the string! This is what I tried so far:

```
///// Form1
private void btn_myClass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myClass myObj = new myClass();
    myObj.NewListEntry += myObj_NewListEntry;
    Thread thrmyClass = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myObj.ThreadMethod));
    thrmyClass.Start();
}

private void myObj_NewListEntry(Object objSender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        // Here I want to add my string from the worker-thread to the textbox!
        richTextBox1.Text += "TEXT"; // I want: richTextBox1.Text += myStringFromWorkerThread;
    });
}
```

---

```
///// myClass (working thread...)
class myClass
{
    public event EventHandler NewListEntry;

    public void ThreadMethod()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    protected virtual void OnNewListEntry(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler newListEntry = NewListEntry;
        if (newListEntry != null)
        {
            newListEntry(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        ///// Do some things and generate strings, such as "test"...
        string test = "test";


        // Here I want to pass the "test"-string! But how to do that??
        OnNewListEntry(EventArgs.Empty); // I want: OnNewListEntry(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Subclass `EventArgs` and add your string as a property.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like this

```
public class NewListEntryEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly string test;

    public NewListEntryEventArgs(string test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public string Test
    {
        get { return this.test; }
    }
}
```

then you declare your class like this

```
class MyClass
{
    public delegate void NewListEntryEventHandler(
        object sender,
        NewListEntryEventArgs args);

    public event NewListEntryEventHandler NewListEntry;

    protected virtual void OnNewListEntry(string test)
    {
        if (NewListEntry != null)
        {
            NewListEntry(this, new NewListEntryEventArgs(test));
        }
    }
}
```

and in the subscribing `Form`

```
private void btn_myClass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.NewListEntry += NewListEntryEventHandler;
    ...
}

private void NewListEntryEventHandler(
    object sender,
    NewListEntryEventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {             
                this.NewListEntryEventHandler(sender, e);
            });
        return;
    }

    richTextBox1.Text += e.Test;
}
```

---

I've taken the liberty of making the `NewListEntryEventArgs` class immutable, since that makes sense. I've also partially corrected your naming conventions, simplified and corrected where expedient.

Comment: Thanks, but I get error "The best overloaded method match for 'declaration' has some invalid arguments" at **this.BeginInvoke(NewListEntryEventHandler, sender, e);**

Comment: My error, that should take a delegate instead of a method group. I've improved my code.

Comment: OMG events are a PITA

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a new class by inheriting off EventArgs.

Answer (score 3):

Create your own version of the `EventArgs`.

Do it like this:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public string MyEventString {get; set; }

   public MyEventArgs(string myString)
   {
       this.MyEventString = myString;
   }
}
```

Then in your code replace the `EventArgs` with `MyEventArgs` and create an `MyEventArgs` object with your string in it.

Then you can access it by using the `MyEventArgs` instance `.MyEventString`.

So you would do something like this:

```
///// myClass (working thread...)
class myClass
{
    public event EventHandler NewListEntry;

    public void ThreadMethod()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    protected virtual void OnNewListEntry(MyEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler newListEntry = NewListEntry;
        if (newListEntry != null)
        {
            newListEntry(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        ///// Do some things and generate strings, such as "test"...
        string test = "test";

        OnNewListEntry(new MyEventArgs(test));
    }
}
```

And in your form:

```
private void myObj_NewListEntry(Object objSender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        // Here I want to add my string from the worker-thread to the textbox!
        richTextBox1.Text += e.MyEventString;
    });
}
```

Comment: When I add **crawler.NewListEntry += crawler_NewListEntry;** to my Form1, I get error: No overload that matches the delegate System.EventHandler'. ??

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to inherit `EventArgs` and add a `string` property, and then make your event of type `EventHandler<YourEventArgs>`, but that is a classic case for the `BackgroundWorker`.

Sample here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

and here:
[C# backgroundWorker reports string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289310/c-sharp-backgroundworker-reports-string)