# Pulling data from a continously running thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, udpclient

I'm working a on project that continuously listens for packets on UDP port 514 (syslog).  When a packet is received I need to parse the message so it can be displayed on my main form in a DataGridView control.

I have it so it updates the DataGridView with new messages, but I could get over 100 syslog messages for the same thing from my firewall so I want to search my dataGrid, see if the message already exists, and then update a "Hit count" column instead of making a new row for duplicate messages.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to invoke my DataGridView in a foreach loop.  I'm not returning the value from the thread, I'm processing the data as it comes in, so I need to invoke the DataGridView control from the UI thread.

My code so far:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var udpCap = await Task.Run(() => captureSyslog());
}
public async Task<string> captureSyslog()
{
    var listener = new UdpClient(514, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
    var ep = default(IPEndPoint);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {                    
            var data = listener.Receive(ref ep);
            string incomingSyslog = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            outputMessage(incomingSyslog);
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            outputMessage(ex2.ToString());
        }
    }
}
private void outputMessage(string txt)
{
    string[] chopped = txt.Split(',');
    string descrip = chopped[32];
    string severity = chopped[34];
    string paloalto = chopped[59];
    int rowIndex = -1;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in syslogOutput.Rows)
    {
        try
        {
            if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(descrip) | row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(paloalto))
            {
                //Code to update DataGridView
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex3){ debugLabel1.Invoke(new Action(() => debugLabel1.Text = ex3.ToString()));}
    }
    if (syslogOutput.InvokeRequired)
    {
        syslogOutput.Invoke(new Action(() => syslogOutput.Rows.Add("1", chopped[59], chopped[34], chopped[32])));
    }
}
```

When the code is run like this, I get a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" which makes sense because the "syslogOuput" DataGridControl doesn't exist in the thread that's calling it.  However the "syslogOutput.Invoke" line farther down works because it's being pulled in from the main UI thread.

Additionally, I *could* update my datagrid with the udpCap var in the Form1_load method, but when I do that I just get one message and the Task.Run thread quits.

So I guess my question can be phrased two ways:

1. How can I invoke a control in a foreach loop?

and/or

2. How can I get a return value from a task without ending the task that's returning the value?

**UPDATE:**
I dumped the Task and used the BackgroundWorker feature to capture the syslog messages.  I abused the UserState in the ProgressChanged method to pass the syslog string so I can parse and then display it to my DataGridView natively in the UI thread.  As far as I can tell the BackgroundWorker thread will run forever if there isn't a cancellation and/or the ReportProgress method never receives a "100" indicating that the process is 100% complete.

New code:

```
namespace ASA_SyslogCapture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
            bgWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgWorker_ProgressChanged);
            bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }
        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //put udp code here
            var listener = new UdpClient(514, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            var ep = default(IPEndPoint);
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var data = listener.Receive(ref ep);
                    string incomingSyslog = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                    bgWorker.ReportProgress(0,incomingSyslog);
                }
                catch (Exception ex2) { debugLabel1.Text = ex2.ToString(); }
            }            
        }
        void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            debugLabel1.Text = e.UserState as String; //this will eventually be my datagridview code            
        }        
    }
}
```

Huge thanks to this thread for the suggestion to use UserState to pass the string:  [C# backgroundWorker reports string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289310/c-sharp-backgroundworker-reports-string)